# Split a string of file input field

Tags: javascript

I need to grab a value from input field in a form, i need only the file name. The string looks like so:

```
var str = 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\file_name.ext';
```

If i try to run (yes, the backslash is escaped)

```
str.split(\\)[str.length-1]
```

It does not work, as the slashes in the string aren't escaped. Simple `console.log(str)` gives me `C:UsersUserDesktopile_name.ext` and you see where the problem is. How do i get around that?

Comment: post some (more) code, maybe?

Comment: it seems to me you have mispelled the `split`'s argument

Comment: you mean you want only "file_name" in your output

Answer (score 2):

```
'C:\Users\User\Desktop\file_name.ext'.split(/\\|//).pop();
```

Assume the backslashes are escaped.  I'm confusing people by escaping my backslashes.  The above string is "as is".

Comment: If only i could have my string with escaped slashes in the first place. My string is `'C:\Users\User\Desktop\file_name.ext'`

Comment: What do you mean?  If you code a string you have to escape the slashes.  When you print the string out to the console, you won't see the escaped slashes.  Your string in your question is invalid the way it is presented in code.

Comment: Sigh ... my string comes as it gets since is the .val() of the file input field. Check the solution i posted.

Comment: @Rastur try my new solution.  It will split on front and backslashes now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the backslashes in your string:

```
"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\file_name.ext".split("\\").pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\file_name.ext';

var parts = str.split('\\');
var result = parts[parts.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution, and link to fiddle [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GMnX/3/)

```
$(function () {
function getFileName(path) {
    return path.match(/[-_\w]+[.][\w]+$/i)[0];
}

$('#data_up').change(function () {
    var fileName = $(this).val();
    $('#data').val('somepath/' + getFileName(fileName));
});
});
```